# Topic Modelling with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to do Topic Modelling with Tensorflow, I know there are algorithms like LDA, but is there any neural network representation in Tensorflow which can be used to do the same thing better or atleast on par with LDA.
Any tips /answers will be greatly appreciated. Also if you can please provide examples of source code etc?